# Understanding the architecture of type traits

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I would like to phrase this question the best possible way, based on my current understanding of `type traits`.

My understanding is that all template classes in `type traits` inherit from `std::integral_constant`, which wraps the representation of both the `value` that the template class has been instantiated with, and its corresponding `type`. Further, the common template classes in `type traits` inherit from the helper alias template of `std::integral_constant`, viz., `std::bool_constant`, as evinced by their definitions.

For instance, in the case of `std::is_arithmetic`, the type of `value` inherited from `std::integral_constant` is `bool`, which implies that the template class inherits from `std::bool_constant`. Further, the template class `std::is_arithmetic` also inherits the `operator bool` from its underlying base, which is supposed to convert the object to `bool` and (possibly return that as the result in `value`).

So my question is: how does the whole semantics tie in together?

In the case of an instance of  `std::is_arithmetic<2>`, if one were to assume that the base is `std::integral_constant<typename T, T v>`, `T` becomes `int` and and `v` becomes `2`. However, since most of the common template classes in `type traits` evidently inherit from `std::bool_constant`, how does the base class instantiation happen in the first place? And what is the underlying logic for (possible) conversion of value to `true` or `false`, as returned by the inherited `operator bool`?

Comment: I would think, you wouldn't use `std::is_arithmetic<2>` but something like `std::is_arithmetic<int>`, `std::is_arithmetic<MyClass>`. As far as I know type traits work on types not on values.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of `integral_constant`:

```
template <typename T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
    static constexpr T value = v;

    using value_type = T;
    using type = integral_constant; // the current instantiation

    constexpr   operator T() const noexcept { return v; }
    constexpr T operator()() const noexcept { return v; }
};
```

So there are three ways to access the value of an `integral_constant` (or a derived class therefrom):

- `integral_constant<T, v>::value`, where the static data member `value` is used;
- `integral_constant<T, v>{}()`, where the `operator()` is called on an object of type `integral_constant<T, v>`; and
- `integral_constant<T, v>{}` implicitly converted to bool.

`bool_constant` is just an alias template:

```
template <bool B>
using bool_constant = integral_constant<bool, B>;

using true_type = bool_constant<true>;
using false_type = bool_constant<false>;
```

Now let's consider an actual type trait.  Take `is_same` for example:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same :false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> :true_type {};
```

It derives from `true_type` (namely `integral_constant<bool, true>`) if the types are the same, or `false_type` (namely `integral_constant<bool, false>`) otherwise.  So, you can use it in the three ways mentioned:

```
static_assert(is_same<int, int>::value); // use ::value member
static_assert(is_same<int, int>{}());    // use operator()
static_assert(is_same<int, int>{});      // use operator bool
```

You can also use `::type` to extract the underlying `integral_constant` base class, and `::value_type` to extract the type of the value:

```
static_assert(is_same<true_type, is_same<int, int>::type>{});
static_assert(is_same<bool, is_same<int, int>::value_type>{});
```

In C++17, we have another way to access the value: `is_same_v<int, int>`.

```
static_assert(is_same_v<int, int>);      // since C++17
```

This is no magic; `is_same_v` is simply a variable template that is defined to be the corresponding value:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;
```